# Should __iadd__ return a new object or manipulate self?

Tags: python, oop

I am quite new to python (to oop in general) an im am I wonder what the expectations on `__iadd__` are. Should it create a new object or modify the existing one?

So if I consider for instance a class of Fractions and add two using `+=`:

```
q1 = Fract(1, 2) #q1 = 1/2
q2 = Fract(2, 3) #q2 = 2/3
id1 = id(q1)
q1 += q2 #q1 = 5/6
id2 = id(q2)
```

Is now the expectation `id1 == id2`? 
Is this just a question of style or makes this differences in real world applications?

I tried this with the build in `complex` class and there it seams that a new object is created.

Comment: Instances of `complex` are immutable, so `z1 += z2` and `z1 = z1 + z2` would have the same semantics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a mutable object, you should manipulate `self` *and* return `self` (not a new object). If you define `__iadd__` with something like

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.n += ...
    self.d += ...
```

the function will return `None`, which is what gets assigned to the name `q1`. If you have *another* reference to the object, you'll see it has been updated in place, but `q1` will no longer refer to it.

To construct a small example, let's look at `Fract.__imul__` that doesn't return `self` (as the implementation is simpler than `__iadd__`):

```
class Fract:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.n = x
        self.d = y

    def __imul__(self, other):
        self.n *= other.n
        self.d *= other.d

x1 = Fract(1,2)
x2 = x1

y = Fract(1,2)

x1 *= y
```

After you run this code, you'll see that `x1` is now bound to `None`, but `x2` is still bound to the original instance of `Fract`, which now has `x2.d == 4` as expected.

So even if you want to update the left-hand operand in place, `__iadd__` et al. still needs to return `self` in order to keep the name referring to the same value.

If you want `Fract` to be *immutable* (like `int` or `complex`), return a new object instead.

```
def __imul__(self, other):
    return Fract(self.n*other.n, self.d*other.d)
```

Answer (score 0):

since your `Fract` class keeps a float then should behave as a float, so let's look at what happens with the floats:

```
q1 =  1 / 2
q2 = 2 / 3
id1 = id(q1)
q1 += q2
id2 = id(q1)

print(id1 == id2)
# ouptut: False
```

so in the flaots case `__iadd__` returns a new object, similar your `Fract` class should return a new object.

of course, if your `Fract` class is more complex keeping the state of other variables then make sense to manipulate and return *`self`*