# Should <instance>.<property> += v call the property's setter?

Tags: python

Given

```
class TameWombat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stomach = []
    def __iadd__(self, v):
        self.stomach += v
        return self

class Fred:
    def __init__(self):
        self._pet = TameWombat()
    @property
    def wombat(self):
        return self._pet
    @wombat.setter
    def wombat(self, v):
        raise ValueError("Fred only wants this particular wombat, thanks.")
```

we cannot use the `__iadd__()` method of the `TameWombat` directly with the property:

```
>>> fred = Fred()
>>> 
>>> fred.wombat += 'delicious food'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in wombat
ValueError: Fred only wants this particular wombat, thanks.
```

Yet we know that `+=` here applies to the result of the getter, not to `fred` himself:

- [How to implement __iadd__ for a Python property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987949/how-to-implement-iadd-for-a-python-property)
- [Should __iadd__ return a new object or manipulate self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029429/should-iadd-return-a-new-object-or-manipulate-self)

What's going on?

Comment: You implement `__iadd__` for `TameWombat` - well, now the underlying object can be mutated in place. It does not eliminate the step of "back assignment": `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. Here's why you need to `return self`. Your call still desugars to `fred.wombat = fred.wombat + 'delicious food'`. It's not specific to property: given attribute `foo`, `self.foo += 1` desugars roughly to `self.foo = (getattr(self.foo, '__iadd__', None) or getattr(self.foo, '__add__'))(1)`.

Comment: Check e.g. [`operator` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators) with neat explanation or [core docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__) with smth similar.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that

```
fred.wombat += 'delicious food'
```

will indeed use the getter to find Fred's wombat, and feed her the delicious food. However, it *then* calls `fred.wombat`'s setter with the result of the `__iadd__()`. So you should write the setter as

```
    @wombat.setter
    def wombat(self, v):
        if v==self._pet:
            return
        raise ValueError("Fred only wants this particular wombat, thanks.")
```

I don't know where this is documented.

This is rather a gotcha, because it looks very much as though the interpreter was calling the setter directly, without interacting with the existing wombat at all.

Comment: Was curious and found this answer/discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546707/1394353  note the “whyyyy?” part.